# Excel VBA copy the value of a label from Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to retrieve the value  "CONGE STATUTAIRE"  from the following html code

```
<span class="DescriptionLabel" id="lblProjectDescription">CONGE STATUTAIRE</span>
```

I've tried this

```
nom_proj = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("DescriptionLabel")(0).innerText
```

The code pass this line without problem but the the value of `nom_proj` is " ",  and I would have hope to get  `"CONGE STATUTAIRE"` for result.

Could anyone tells me what's wrong with it?   The rest of my code is working i.e.  I can retrieve value by using the `getelementbyID` method.

Any help will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `getElementById()` method, to make sure it can return only *one* HTML element and not a collection of objects:

```
nom_proj = IE.Document.getElementById("lblProjectDescription").innerText
```

However, the reason why you get `""` is most probably that the collection returned by `getElementsByClassName()` has more than one element (often, when retrieving object by class names).
Which means: in the `Document` of your browser there will be *most probably* more elements that are styled with the CSS class `DescriptionLabel`; for example, something like this:

```
<div name="emptyRow" class = "DescriptionLabel"></div>
```

You can test if there are more than one element by:

1) either, adding a watcher to `IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("DescriptionLabel")`;

2) or, printing all the elements inside, I bet my hat you'll find inside more than one:

```
For Each obj In IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("DescriptionLabel")
    Debug.Print obj.InnerText
Next obj
```

**GENERAL SUGGESTION**: if an HTML object has an *id*, use the `getElementByID`; that method returns a *single* object, not a collection, so even if you would be sure that the collection will contain a unique element, it would anyway be less clean and efficient in terms of coding.

Comment: Wouhou!!  Tx alot Matteo NNZ.  Works like a charm.  You can keep your hat!